# Error when ffmpeg .png to .mov using dnxhd codec

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing

I would like to append a frame from a `.png` file to an existing `.mov` movie.

I have some existing commands passed on to me and I'm trying to work out why they aren't working.

The first command does successfully make a mov, if the codec isnt specified.
However i'd like to know why the following command doesn't work, when the codec is specified.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i X:/slate.png -r 24000/1001 -frames:v 1 -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos:out_color_matrix=bt709,pad=1920:1080:0:0:black,setsar=1,fps=24000/1001 -codec:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhd -pix_fmt yuv422p -b:v 116275660 -g 1 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -y X:/slate.mov
```

The error I get is

```
[dnxhd @ 000001d15e15a780] video parameters incompatible with DNxHD. Valid DNxHD profiles:
.........
ERROR initializing output stream 0:0 -- ERROR while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion FAILED!
```

Any idea how I can specify the codec in such a way the command still completes?